# passing variables and functions to Hot-Column directive in ngHandsontable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, handsontable

I'm trying to pass variables and functions into the hot-column directive which is part of the ngHandsontable.js, in which i'm using ng-repeat. In the following example `DATEFORMAT` is a global variable, and `getDropdownOptions` a function in the same $scope as `tableMetaData` which is recognized in the hot-column directive.

```
    <hot-table
            data-settings="{colHeaders: colHeaders, afterChange: afterChange, columnSorting: true, sortIndicator: true, manualColumnResize: true, wordWrap: false}"
            data-rowHeaders="true"
            data-dataRows="tableData">
        <hot-column
                data="{{tCol.DATA}}"
                data-ng-repeat="tCol in tableMetaData | orderBy: 'SEQUENCE' | filter: {DISPLAY: true}"
                data-type="{{tCol.TYPE}}"
                data-date-format="DATEFORMAT"
                data-source="getDropdownOptions"
                data-read-only="{{tCol.READONLY}}"
                data-title="'{{tCol.TITLE}}'">
        </hot-column>
    </hot-table>
```

The problem is that the directive gets the variable and function as undefined. This happens because in the hot-column's link it loops through all the attributes and $eval's them. Here's the relevant code:

```
    link: function (scope, element, attributes, controllerInstance) {
      var column = {};

      for (var i in attributes) {
        if (attributes.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
          if (i.charAt(0) !== '$' && typeof column[i] === 'undefined') {
            if (i === 'data') {
              column['data'] = attributes[i];
            }
            else {
              if (i!=='ngRepeat') { // this if is my addition in order to allow ng-repeat
                column[i] = scope.$eval(attributes[i]); // this line is part of the original directive
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I tried to exclude the function from being '$eval'ed but then only the string is passed. Same with the variable.

How can I make this work?

**EDIT**:
I've managed to pass variables by using eval instead of $eval in the handsontable code. This still doesn't solve how to pass functions. Here's the eval fix:

```
    else {
      if (i!=='ngRepeat') {
        if (i == 'dateFormat') {
          column[i] = eval(attributes[i]);

        } else {
            column[i] = scope.$eval(attributes[i]);
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Probably best way to do that (pass functions and object values) would be isolated scopes.

Comment: the variables and methods are part of an isolated scope wrapping these directives. As I mentioned - the directive does recognize `tableMetaData` which is part of the same scope